# Security of encrypted data and decrypting key

Tags: encryption

I am writing a python program in which I use encryption. The user can set the password and when it will be an input, the database will be decrypted. However, the function needs the decryption key to decrypt. So I thought about hiding that key somewhere(encryption and decryption key will be generated dynamically which means that the user on new device will have another decryption key.). I have no idea where I could hide it, so program could use it, but the user could not crack it.

Comment: I don't understand the actual problem here. Why do you want to stop the user from decrypting the database if they can access the database with the password anyway? And if you want to allow access only if the password is provided - why not base the encryption key directly or indirectly on the users password?

Comment: to protect against someone on another machine stealing and then reading this data, you could use your machine's serial # as part or all of the key.  You just read that hardware-based info each time: https://gist.github.com/angeloped/3febaaf71ac083bc2cd5d99d775921d0

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a decryption (or encryption) key anywhere that a program can use it but the user whose permissions the program runs with cannot. This is the same problem DRM schemes have. There's no trust boundary between the user and their software; the software can't do anything that the user couldn't write software to do.

There are ways to hide the key (such as storing it in an external security module - either hardware or software that runs in a different, more restricted security context - but such systems will still encrypt/decrypt whatever the user's software asks them to, so not actually having the key is a meaningless distinction for a local "attacker" like this.

Assuming you're not simply deriving the key from the user's entered password (and never storing it persistently, at least not in plain text, anywhere), you might as well store the key in the user's profile directory (alternatively, in an OS-specific key store, which Windows and MacOS provide), with permissions set such that only the user can read it. Obviously this doesn't prevent the user from reading it with their own software, but they could also just modify your Python code or run it in a debugger and extract the key that way, even if there was some way to more securely store it.